# Discontinuities in Anti-derivatives?

Tags: calculus, integration, continuity, riemann-integration

I've been having a look at whether antiderivatives have discontinuities when the integrand is a function that is piecewise continuous, or it has a finite number of discontinuities while still being bounded.

If I were to consider a function $f(x)$ that was integrable over $[a,b]$, but not continuous (only piecewise continuous here) everywhere, would the antiderivative, $\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$ where $x \in[a,b]$ be continuous, or discontinuous?

I've found an answer (see below image for context) that states that "*for any such function, an antiderivative always exists except possibly at the points of discontinuity*." What confuses me here is the fact that it is uncertain.

Thus my question is as follows;

**How would I be able to tell if the antiderivative exists or not at certain points (and how would I find what these points are) if I were given a function $f(x)$ that was integrable over $[a,b]$ but has a finite amount of discontinuities?**

Thanks!

[image: Does every function have an anti-derivative]
Source: [https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/existantideriv.html#:~:text=Most%20functions%20you%20normally%20encounter,at%20the%20points%20of%20discontinuity](https://www.math.toronto.edu/mathnet/questionCorner/existantideriv.html#:%7E:text=Most%20functions%20you%20normally%20encounter,at%20the%20points%20of%20discontinuity).

Comment: Please do not rely on images. They don’t display the same everywhere (for me, this is impossibly small, for example). They are not searchable, either within the site or by web search engines. And screen readers cannot handle them, so your post is inaccessible to people who use them. The site has *excellent* typesetting capabilities using MathJax; please avail yourself of them and put the information into the post as text.

Comment: $F$ will be continuous for all $x\in[a,b]$ but will not be differentiable when $f$ is discontinuous. It's not really an antiderivative for this reason, I think that's what they meant; since we cannot differentiate $F$ to get $f$ at the points of discontinuity it's not an antiderivative. I think the definite integral is still continuous, though.